# ignore character within html tags while counting characters

Tags: php, html, split

in my current template, i have a large block of text that comes in from the user. the block is then split at the 600 character mark and placed into a specific div on the page, the rest of the block is placed near the bottom of the page. this works fine, but a problem arises when there are a lot of links added near the beginning of the post.

the `<a href='...'></a>` is being counted towards the total character count. i always want to split the block at 600.

is there an easy way for me to find out the length of the html characters? that way I can just add them to the split_length. or any other ideas? ways to ignore the html characters entirely?

edit:
i should be clear i WANT the links to stay...

Comment: If the text contains HTML you need an HTML parser to split it, otherwise you can get unbalanced tags. You could also hide everything below N pixels instead of splitting, it's much easier.

Comment: This is not trivial.  Neither RegEx nor HTML parsers will help you much here.  If I were trying to do this myself I would likely `strip_tags` initially to check there's more than 600 characters, then walk through the original string character by character tracking whether I'm countable (or in a tag), and what tags are "open" (so I can close them after splitting).  Then just keep walking until you count 600 countables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's function [**strip_tags()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and then count the characters.

Comment: well, i have a `$txt` variable which has the entire string in it (well over 600 characters. a couple paragraphs) and I just split it every time after 600 characters regardless of the content inside... so just adding `strip_tags()` to my variable splits it properly but removes the links...

Comment: Well, then looking at the documentation of strip_tags() from Adeine's answer, you can passing in anchor tag as a second argument. Then apply [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to the anchor tags according to your specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the HTML code, and split your text at the exact count. For that, use:

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

> This function tries to return a string with all NUL bytes, HTML and
>   PHP tags stripped from a given str. It uses the same tag stripping
>   state machine as the fgetss() function.

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for more info.

Comment: i used `strip_tags` on my text block and now my length is right but all of my links are gone.